# Azure-mobile-apps-net-client PushAsync wrong order

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm calling `await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();` to push new created/updated objects to the server. However not everytime the order in the __operations table is adhered to.

Example (simplified) for a typical `__operations` table in my app:

```
1) Create some record in Project table
2) Update some record in User table
3) Create another record in Project table
```

However when I look at the server output, it tells me that 1) and 3) are POSTed and then 2) is PATCHed.

I thougt the `__operations` are exactly replayed in the same order to the server, as they were made on the client?

Some additional info:

I call `await itemTable.PullAsync("allItems", itemTable.CreateQuery());` directly after the `PushAsync()` moreover record 2) contains some data which the server does not accept and responds with an http error for testing. The error message is correctly shown on the server side, however after 1) and 3) are POSTED.

Answer (score 2):

The operations table collapses to minimize the number of transactions / round trips to the server.  In your case, what you will see is:

1) record A is updated

2) record B is updated

3) removed, because we already have record A being updated

Thus you will see 2 records, not three.  Record A is only sent once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sry, I'm afraid that I don't understand your explanation. The numbers 1), 2) and 3) in my example stand for 3 different rows in my local sqlite database __operations table. 1) is a newly created object of type "Project" which is not yet on the server. 2) Is an update (was updated on client) to an "User" object, which was downloaded from the server some time ago and 3) Is a **different** newly created "Project". 1) and 3) have different ids and never existed before.

Answer (score 0):

> it tells me that 1) and 3) are POSTed and then 2) is PATCHed.

PushAsync helps us to push the changes to Mobile App backend. As I know, the wrong order maybe caused by your Mobile App API. For example, if the update user table will use 200ms and create a record will use 100ms. the order will be 1)/3)->2). If create a record will use 300ms, the order will be 2)->1)/3).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made a few changes, it seems, that now the order of the requests is the same as in the __operations table. Am I right, that the azure-mobile-apps-net-client SDK replays the transactions to the server always in the same order as they are in the __operations table?